# Python self error

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, self

I'm working on a Python program, and I'm using a function from jasper project that contains "self". The function should recognize when a word is said. This is my program:

```
import logging
import tempfile
import wave
import audioop
import pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr

def stt(file):
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.WavFile(file) as source:              # use "test.wav" as the audio source
        audio = r.record(source)                        # extract audio data from the file
        return r.recognize(audio)   # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition


def passiveListen(self, PERSONA):
    """
    Listens for PERSONA in everyday sound. Times out after LISTEN_TIME, so
    needs to be restarted.
        """

    THRESHOLD_MULTIPLIER = 1.8
    RATE = 16000
    CHUNK = 1024

    # number of seconds to allow to establish threshold
    THRESHOLD_TIME = 1

    # number of seconds to listen before forcing restart
    LISTEN_TIME = 10

    # prepare recording stream
    stream = self._audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                              channels=1,
                              rate=RATE,
                              input=True,
                              frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    # stores the audio data
    frames = []

    # stores the lastN score values
    lastN = [i for i in range(30)]

    # calculate the long run average, and thereby the proper threshold
    for i in range(0, RATE / CHUNK * THRESHOLD_TIME):

        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)

        # save this data point as a score
        lastN.pop(0)
        lastN.append(self.getScore(data))
        average = sum(lastN) / len(lastN)

    # this will be the benchmark to cause a disturbance over!
    THRESHOLD = average * THRESHOLD_MULTIPLIER

    # save some memory for sound data
    frames = []

    # flag raised when sound disturbance detected
    didDetect = False

    # start passively listening for disturbance above threshold
    for i in range(0, RATE / CHUNK * LISTEN_TIME):

        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)
        score = self.getScore(data)

        if score > THRESHOLD:
            didDetect = True
            break

    # no use continuing if no flag raised
    if not didDetect:
        print "No disturbance detected"
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        return (None, None)

    # cutoff any recording before this disturbance was detected
    frames = frames[-20:]

    # otherwise, let's keep recording for few seconds and save the file
    DELAY_MULTIPLIER = 1
    for i in range(0, RATE / CHUNK * DELAY_MULTIPLIER):

        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)

    # save the audio data
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()

    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b') as f:
        wav_fp = wave.open(f, 'wb')
        wav_fp.setnchannels(1)
        wav_fp.setsampwidth(pyaudio.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16))
        wav_fp.setframerate(RATE)
        wav_fp.writeframes(''.join(frames))
        wav_fp.close()
        f.seek(0)
        # check if PERSONA was said
        transcribed = stt(f)

    if any(PERSONA in phrase for phrase in transcribed):
        return (THRESHOLD, PERSONA)

    return (False, transcribed)

print passiveListen(self.persona)
```

Now the problem is that I'm starting with python and I don't know how to use that function. Actually I get this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Prueba.py", line 112, in <module>
    print passiveListen(self.persona)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

I've also tried with `print passiveListen(self.persona)` but it doesn't work anyway. I've been looking at the github project to see how is this function used but I can't get any information (https://github.com/jasperproject/jasper-client/). 
Note that "persona" should be a name or a word, example: Alexa.
Could somebody help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: `self` is usually used inside a class. I'm guessing you copied some code from a class method and are trying to run it outside a class.

Comment: You seem to have copied this [function](https://github.com/jasperproject/jasper-client/blob/f12fa52c7badd7acc10fc54fdf99bdddc6b68c78/client/mic.py#L89) from within a class in an existing project. Maybe instead you want to edit the existing working code to print the data, or in your code that uses the library simply print the result of the existing code.

Comment: Yes, I've copied that function, so what sould I do for it to work correctly outside of the function? If I delete all the self, I get this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Prueba.py", line 112, in <module>
    print passiveListen("HOLA")
  File "Prueba.py", line 32, in passiveListen
    stream = _audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
NameError: global name '_audio' is not defined
`

Comment: Do you know about classes in Python? This code calls other functions in the class (e.g. `getScore`) and to "fix" it you effectively need to copy the entire class. Have a read of https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html, it will help you understand the comments and answers here. What I think you really want to do is use this library to create an instance of this class (have a look at any docs for this project) and simply print the result of `my_instance.passiveListen(PERSONA)`

Answer (score 2):

Listen to the error. You have not defined `self` as a variable. The error originates from your last row, where you're using `self` outside the function.